# How to map one-field value object by code in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I have an `Account` class, which contains `Email`, `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `PasswordHash`.
I want to create Value-Objects for `Email` and `PasswordHash`, And using regular expressions on constructors to get rid of plain strings and be sure that these fields contain valid data, but I'm questioned, how to persist this `Account` entity via NHibernate?
How can I instruct NHibernate to store this values as strings in database, but to restore it as Value-Objects when I ask for it?
Do I have to write DTO's for it and map it back and forward or is there a better way?

Comment: If you think that this is a task for data layer, use Custom Type...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate table for Value Objects on NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331178/separate-table-for-value-objects-on-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Domain Model:

```
public class Email: ValueObjectBase<Email>
{
    private readonly string _address;
    public Email(string address)
    {
        _address = address;
        Validate(); //check RegX
    }
}

public class FullName: ValueObjectBase<FullName>
{
    private readonly string _firstName;
    private readonly string _lastName;

    public FullName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        this.Validate();
    }

    public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; } }

    public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } }
}

public class Account : EntityBase<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual FullName FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual Email Email { get; set; }
}
```

NHibernate Mapping:

```
public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
{
        public AccountMap()
        {
            LazyLoad();
            Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
            Component(c => c.FullName, m =>
            {
               m.Map(Reveal.Member<FullName>("_firstName")).Column("FirstName").Length(30).Not.Nullable();
               m.Map(Reveal.Member<FullName>("_lastName")).Column("LastName").Length(40).Not.Nullable();
            });

            Component(c => c.Email, m => m.Map(Reveal.Member<Email>("_address")).Column("EmailAddress").Not.Nullable());


        }
}
```